# Wat is the correct term for 'historic average'?

Tags: functions

I've got the following array of numbers:

`{2, 4, 8, 1, 3}`

I've got a function that will shows the 'historic average' for every number:

`{2, 3, 4.667, 3.75, 3.6}`

I'm not a mathematician, but I would like to know how this function is called. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [cumulative moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

Comment: Nice! Thanks :D